# SVG transition on hover fails in Safari 9.1.2 (11601.7.7)

Tags: css, svg, safari, css-transitions

I am trying to fade text and .svg to another color on hover.

```css
a{
  color: #ff0000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  transition: color 1s linear;
}
a:hover{
  color: #000;
}
svg{
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 2em;
}
path{
  transition: fill 1s linear;
  fill: #ff0000;
 }
a:hover path{
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com" class="tweet-this">
    <i class="icon icon-twitter">
        <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>twitter</title><path d="M24.679 10.658c-.651.281-1.35.471-2.083.556.749-.437 1.324-1.13 1.595-1.955-.701.405-1.477.699-2.303.858-.662-.687-1.604-1.116-2.647-1.116-2.003 0-3.627 1.582-3.627 3.535 0 .277.032.546.094.805-3.014-.147-5.687-1.554-7.476-3.693-.312.522-.491 1.129-.491 1.777 0 1.226.64 2.308 1.614 2.942-.594-.018-1.154-.177-1.643-.442v.045c0 1.712 1.25 3.141 2.909 3.466-.304.081-.625.124-.956.124-.234 0-.461-.022-.682-.063.462 1.404 1.801 2.426 3.388 2.455-1.241.948-2.805 1.513-4.505 1.513-.292 0-.581-.017-.865-.049 1.605 1.003 3.512 1.588 5.56 1.588 6.671 0 10.32-5.385 10.32-10.056l-.01-.457c.709-.498 1.323-1.121 1.81-1.829" fill="#fff"></path></svg>
    </i>
    Tweet this
</a>
```

The transition on the .svg does not fire in Safari, but it does in Chrome and Firefox.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20012937/281067) states that you need a starting and an end color, which I have.

How can I make the transition work in Safari as well?

Comment: I have seen evidence from someone on the same version of Safari that the transition works correctly on their machine. Maddening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was pointed to an [article on rrott.com titled "Bug with CSS transition animation for SVG in Safari."](https://rrott.com/blog/svg/issue-with-css-transition-animation-in-safari.html)

Juicy bits:

> I found that the transition stops working for all the visited links
>   and that could be the reason why I was not able to reproduce the issue
>   on one machine while it is failed on another.

and

> Sadly, changing :visited pseudo in CSS as well as using xmlns:xlink
>   inside of SVG does not make transition working again and there are no
>   hacks there.

The article also lists a number of possible solutions:

> I see several solutions there but, unfortunately, none of them are
>   good enough:
>
> 1. add some random data to the link(something like /#timestamp that looks
>      ugly but the link will always be ‘unvisited’ for the users).
> 2. Do not use animation and inlined SVG in links.
> 3. Put link above SVG image using position and z-index so the image is
>      'clickjacked’. It works but requires additional js code to handle
>      image’s hover event to not loose on hover animation, e.g. add Jquery
>      code that will handle clicks on logo and change window.location.
> 4. Dynamically move SVG outside of the link in case of Safari.
> 5. Leave it as is if you have low amount of Safari users.

I'll go with number 5 for now.

Comment: Instead of JavaScript/jQuery to handle the hover event you can do something like a:hover+svg (provided the <a> is z-index'd above the svg and they're next to each other).